# Run function after DOM change

Tags: jquery, function, dom, shopify, onchange

So I have a Product with 2 options selection, one for the color and one for the size. I have some jQuery that clones the size option selected inside the div.option_trigger. The problem is that if I click on a color option all the options inside size change, including the option selected. So I want that the element that was cloned, gets updated with the new option selected.

Color selector:

```
<div class="custom-swatch color">
  <!-- Selected color -->
  <div class="swatch-color selected"> 
    <input id="swatch-0-nightfall-blue-10963197379" type="radio" name="option-0" value="Nightfall Blue"> 
    <div data-value="Nightfall Blue" class="swatch-element color nightfall-blue-swatch"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="swatch-color"> 
    <input id="swatch-0-phoenix-blue-10963197379" type="radio" name="option-0" value="Phoenix Blue"> 
    <div data-value="Phoenix Blue" class="swatch-element color phoenix-blue-swatch soldout"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This label is cloned depending on the size selected, and needs to be updated after the color selection changes the size selected:

```
<div class="option_trigger">
  <!-- This label gets updated depending on the size selection, and needs to be updated after the color selection change the size selected-->
  <label class="soldout">Medium</label>
</div>
```

These swatch-size options change depending on the color selected, making some sizes available and others soldout:

```
<div class="custom-swatch size">
  <!-- These swatch-size options change depending on the color selected, making some sizes available and others soldout --> 
  <div class="swatch-size"> 
    <input id="swatch-1-2x-large-10963197379" type="radio" name="option-1" value="2X-Large" checked=""> 
    <div data-value="2X-Large" class="swatch-element 2x-large-swatch soldout"> 
      <label class="swatch-label soldout" for="swatch-1-2x-large-10963197379">2X-Large</label>
    </div>
  </div> 
  <div class="swatch-size"> 
    <input id="swatch-1-large-10963197379" type="radio" name="option-1" value="Large"> 
    <div data-value="Large" class="swatch-element large-swatch"> 
      <label class="swatch-label" for="swatch-1-large-10963197379">Large</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- The label inside this selected swatch is the one that gets cloned into div.optio_trigger--> 
  <div class="swatch-size selected"> 
    <input id="swatch-1-medium-10963197379" type="radio" name="option-1" value="Medium"> 
    <div data-value="Medium" class="swatch-element medium-swatch soldout"> 
      <label class="swatch-label soldout" for="swatch-1-medium-10963197379">Medium</label>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And this is the jQuery I wrote to clone the size selected (everything is working good here)

```
$('.custom-swatch.size > .swatch-size > input').each(function(){
  $(this).change(function(){
    var lab = $(this).next().children(); //This is the label selected
    var trigg = $(this).parent().parent().prev(); //This is the div.option_trigger
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('selected');
    $(trigg).append($(lab).clone().removeClass('swatch-label').removeAttr('for'));
    $(trigg).children().last().prevAll().remove();
  });
});
```

And this is what I'm trying to do to clone the label element after the color change and the label selected gets updated. But is not working, I found this approach somewhere else but it's incorrect.

```
$('.swatch-color > input').change(function() {
  $('div.custom-swatch.size > div.swatch-size.selected > div').trigger('updatecomplete');
});
$('div.custom-swatch.size > div.swatch-size.selected > div').on('updatecomplete', function() {
  var labc = $(this).children();
  var trigc = $(this).parent().parent().prev();
  $(trigc).append($(labc).clone().removeClass('swatch-label').removeAttr('for'));
  $(trigc).children().last().prevAll().remove();
});
```

Comment: Off topic: You don't need to wrap your variables in `$()`. They're already jQuery objects.

Comment: Also off-topic: Long chains of DOM traversal are fragile. Instead, target ancestors or descendants by class name in case your markup changes in minor ways: `$closest('.some-class')`